# How to make my own xticklabels on subplot containing years, using dataframe index column with monthly dates?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, label

I have two dataframes with data that I want to present in a subplot consisting of two separate plots. In the first subplot, I want to plot monthly data (df_monthly) of this format (index is Date column):

```
Date                       Col1   ...     Col9
2000-01-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.45   ...     0.34
2000-02-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.56   ...     0.72
2000-03-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.12   ...     0.04
2000-04-01 00:00:00+02:00  0.57   ...     0.98
2000-05-01 00:00:00+02:00  0.39   ...     0.63
...                        ...    ...     ...
...                        ...    ...     ...
```

In the second subplot, I want to plot data of yearly resolution (df_yearly) (the same dataset originally). Format:

```
Date        Column1       Column2        
2000        45.50         2.40
2001        46.70         7.00
2002        50.20         1.20
2003        32.40         3.40
2004        38.90         6.90
.           .             .
.           .             .
.           .             .
```

I want to have xticks in both my plots showing years (that is: 2000, 2001, 2002,...) By default, python does not give this for my plots, so I want to define the xticks myself. Also, this code is part of a program that takes in data of different start and end dates (that is; data does not necessarily start 01-01-2000, but may start earlier or later)

For the yearly plot, I manage to do what I intend to do:

```
years = []
for i in range(df_monthly.index.year.min(), 
                df_monthly.index.year.max(), 1):
    years.append(i)
.
.
.
axes[0].set_xticks(df_yearly.index)
axes[0].set_xticklabels(years)
```

For the monthly plot, things go wrong... Writing

```
axes[1].set_xticks(df_monthly.index.year)
axes[1].set_xticklabels(years)
```

gives thousands of small xticks. Writing

```
axes[1].set_xticks(df_monthly.year.index.unique())
axes[1].set_xticklabels(years)
```

gives thousands of xtick labels "far to the right" of my dataset in the plot that appears.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you explain how you define this `year` variable?

Comment: Also is not clear to me if, in the monthly plot, you want all thicks showing just the years (you will have 12 thicks for that years) or just one thick for each year. I suspect the latter... and in this case, where the thick should be placed? January? February? The first month available?

Comment: Year is the built-in pandas.DatetimeIndex.year. Sorry, I wrote it wrong... It should be 'axes[1].set_xticks(df_monthly.index.year)', not '...year.index'. I have corrected it now. I want one tick for each year, and the ticks should be placed in January.

Answer (score 0):

Here `df` is your monthly dataframe. I assume here that `'Date'` is the index of the dataframe, as suggested by your code.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

#plotting the yearly plot, you have your code for this
axes[0] = ...

#plotting the monthly plot   
axes[1].plot(df['Col1'])
axes[1].plot(df['Col9']) #a call for each column you want to plot

dates = df.index.to_series()
df['YearDup'] = dates.apply(lambda x : x.year).duplicated()
axes[1].set_xticks(dates.loc[~df['YearDup']])

plt.show()
```

The important lines are:

1. ```
   dates = df.index.to_series()
   ```
2. ```
   df['YearDup'] = dates.apply(lambda x : x.year).duplicated()
   ```
3. ```
   axes[1].set_xticks(dates.loc[~df['YearDup']])
   ```

Line 1 makes a series from the index. Needed to use `apply` and `loc` functions.
Line 2 creates a boolean column to mark duplicated of the year using the [pandas duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method.
Line 3 selects only the first occurrence of each year using `loc` an the `'YearDup'` column.
Since now each date has a different year, `matplotlib` is smart enough to use the year only as label of each thick, removing automatically the other parts of the date. If this does not happen (maybe depends on the version, I am not sure) you can set the labels manually with the following line, after line 3 of above code (is an addition, not a replacement):

```
axes[1].set_xticklabels(dates.apply(lambda x : x.year).loc[~df['YearDup']])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and helpful explanation. I get, however, not the exact desired outcome. Using Line 3 gives me a TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.float64' and 'Timestamp'. Using the last line instead of Line 3 gives a plot with one x tick for each year, but with x tick labels for only every second year. They are wrongly placed, so that "2000, 2001, 2002..." are presented as labels, but "2000" is placed where "2001" is supposed to be, and "2001" is placed where "2003" is supposed to be, and so on.

Comment: When I print out the content of df['YearDup'], I get a column where all time steps (each month) is True, except for January each year, which gives False (which I assume sounds right).

Comment: Curious error. It worked for me. I noticed a typo in the code I posted, a missing parenthesis at the end of the line 3. Maybe that was the reason. The last line is an addition, to be used after line 3 (it is not a replacement for line 3). Check my edit. Yes, `df['YearDup']` is supposed to be like that. The first value is set to `False`, its duplicated to `True`.